# Minimizing cost of pipeline by finding optimal locations for stations using dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, minimization

I have a question about dynamic programming that I am trying to describe an algorithm for.

Question:
A pipeline is to be built and you have to decide on the optimal location of the stations along the path that has already been decided. The pipeline connects points x1 and xn and goes through locations x2,x3...x(n-1). There are stations at x1 and xn but part of the problem is to decide whether to build a station at point xi for i = 2,3...n-1.If a station is built the associated cost is bi and if a pipeline is built between stations xi and xj, the corresponding cost is cij. The total cost is the sum of the costs of the station and the corresponding pipeline section costs. The goal is to decide the optimal location of stations so that the total cost is minimized.

We have to describe a general algorithm for this using dynamic programming. 
My approach was to treat this like a rod cutting problem and try to make a matrix and minimize the cost but I am not sure how to deal with the extra variable of the cost of the stations being built as well. How should I approach this problem given the many variables? And how would I develop a recursive formula?
Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: Yes I agree that the question is a bit unclear and also confused me at first, but that is all that was given in the question. I believe since the stations and pipelines all have different costs, there should be an optimal way of doing it.

Comment: What are the criteria for determining whether you build a station at some location? Given your description, it seems like you *always* have to build pipelines between x2 and x3, x3 and x4, etc. Without further information, it looks like the optimum solution is to just build pipelines between adjacent locations, and build no new stations. What am I missing? Or what did you fail to put in your question?

Comment: @JimMischel You have a choice, either build a station, or not. For example, assume that you've chosen to build x2 and x4. One choice then is to build x3 with a cost of `c23 + cx3 + c34`. The other choice is to build a pipeline directly from x2 to x4 at a cost of `c24`.

Comment: @ comp.eng. I would just include the cost of the station in the left-side pipeline. If you have a station at xi, then the cost of extending the pipeline from location `i` to location `j` is `cij + cxj`.

Comment: @JimMischel: The default solution is to build no stations at all, and simply have a single pipe from x1 to xn.  The problem is to find the optimum set of intermediate stations.

Comment: You haven't said what "optimum* means! What is the benefit of building a station at position xi? As far as your problem description is concerned, stations have a cost, but no benefit. Remember that all we know about your problem is what you tell us, and you're not giving us enough information to help you design a solution.

Comment: Dynamic pogramming is roughly the same as memoization, and memoization is another word for caching solutions to subproblems. Your subproblems here are: given that stations were built at locations i and j, i < j, find which intermediate stations have to be built. There are at most O(n^2) such subproblems and by a suitable recursion (it doesn't have to be an explicit formula) you reduce the solution for i=1 j=n to solutions of  these intermediate problems which you cache, as soon as you find them. And this caching cuts the number of the trials to make from exponential to just quadratic..

Comment: There's still stuff you're not telling us. Does it have to go *through* all locations? Or can it just go *to* one or more locations. That is, would a "star" configuration be valid, with just one station and direct pipelines to all the other locations? (I know it wouldn't be optimum, but would it be valid?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical insight in this is that the minimum cost to connect any two points, x*i* and x*j* (call it m*ij*) is independent of the configurations outside of that segment (i.e. x*1* to x*i* and x*j* to x*n*).

Your dynamic programming problem is to index and store each cost as it's found, and the to float partial solutions back up the call tree.

The base case is that the cost to connect two adjacent nodes, x*i* and x*j* (where j=i+1), is simply cij (you can't build a new station there).

The simplest case is when j=i+2; Is it profitable to build a station at i+1.  In algebraic terms, is c(i)(i+2) < b(i+1) + c(i)(i+1) + c(i+1)(i+2) ?

In general, you need to recur on a `find_first_station(i, j)` function.  This should find the location of the lowest-index station to build between stations already at i and j.  For each point 'k`, i<k<j, build a station at`k`, run a pipe`ik`, and then recur with`find_first_station(k, j)`.  Return the solution (all station locations) with the minimum cost for any`k`, or the null list if cij is the minimum cost.

Can you take it from there?

Comment: so if I were to write out the recursive function for this problem, would it be:         C(j) = min { cij + bj + C(j-k)} for 1<k<j ?

Comment: because each time I add pipelines, a station has to be built so I should be able to group (cij and bj) together. Am I correct?

Comment: Correct: since this always considers the lowest-numbered station, it follows that building b*j* implies laying the pipe for c*ij*.  You can combine them.

Comment: That's the important part.  Glad to be of help.